# Как записать value из Fragment из TextInput в компонент Parent в1й TextInput затем в 2й TextInput?

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
    import React, {useState,useRef} from 'react';
import {View, SafeAreaView,TextInput,Button,StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const Parent = ()=>{
    const [name,setName] = useState('')
 const [surname,setSurName] = useState('')
const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false)
    const [isRender, setIsRender] = useState(true)
    const onChangeName = () =>{
        setName(name)
    }
    const [text, setText]=useState ('')
    const ref1 = useRef(null)
    const ref2 = useRef(null)
    const onChangeSurname = () =>{
        setSurName(surname)
    }
const goToChild = () =>{
        if(ref1.current){
            setIsModalVisible(true)
        }
        if(ref2.current){
            setIsModalVisible(true)
        }

    }


    const handleText= (e)=>{
        setText(e)
    }
    const goToParent=()=>{
        if(ref1.current){
            setIsRender(!isRender)
            setName(text)
            setIsModalVisible(false)

        }
        if(ref2.current){
            setIsRender(!isRender)
             setSurName (text)
            setIsModalVisible(false)
        }




    }
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <View>
                <TextInput ref={ref1} value={name}  placeholder='name' onChangeText={onChangeName}/>

        <TextInput value={surname}  ref={ref2} placeholder='surname' onChange={onChangeSurname}/>
            <Button onPress={goToChild} title='GoToChild'/>
            </View>
{isModalVisible &&
(<React.Fragment>
    <View style={styles.child}>
    <TextInput onChangeText={handleText} placeholder='enter-name-or-surname'/>
<Button title='goToParent' onPress= {goToParent}  />
    </View>
    </React.Fragment> )}
                </SafeAreaView>

)
}
export default Parent;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor:'white'
    },
    child:{
        flex:1,
      backgroundColor: 'gray'
    }
})
```

Comment: Присвойте значение name и surname значением из нужного элемента

Comment: Так у меня же присвоен value=name и value= surname в инпутах.

Comment: В handleText добавьте setName(e) setSurName(e). Ну или в goToParent если надо по нажатию кнопки переносить данные

Comment: Сам попробуй неправильно. Сначало нужно сохранить значение name из инпута из Fragment в состояние text. Потом когда нажимаешь на GoToParent этот text чтобы сохранился в состояние name. Со вторым тоже самое вводишь surname и surname сохранился в состояние surname. А потом name и surname передать в TextInput как значение.

Comment: Я вам рассказал, КАК это сделать. Вы повторили. Теперь перечитайте и реализуйте. все set[VALUES] у вас есть, осталось только присвоить правильные значения правильным переменным по нужному событию.

Comment: Попробуйте сделайте сами сначало получилось или нет если нет зачем такие предсказания писать.